# My method is not abstract and cannot override another method

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've been trying to create a music player and part of that requires listening to a time slider. So I've added to the time slide and this is the error I get:

[image]

I've been trying to get my head around how you fix this error and the whole business of overriding.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this error?

**My Code:**

```
public class graphicalController implements Initializable 
{
    //GUI Decleration
    @FXML
    public Button centreButton;
    @FXML
    public Button backButton;
    @FXML
    public Button forwardButton;
    @FXML
    public ToggleButton muteToggle;
    @FXML
    public MenuItem loadFolder;
    @FXML
    public Text nameText;
    @FXML
    public Text albumText;
    @FXML
    public Text timeText;
    @FXML
    public Text artistText;
    @FXML
    public Slider timeSlider;
    @FXML
    public Slider volumeSlider;

    //Controller Decleration
    String absolutePath;
    SongQueue q = new SongQueue();
    MediaPlayer player;
    Status status;
    boolean isPlaying = false;
    boolean isMuted = false;
    boolean isPaused = false;
    private Duration duration;

    /**
     * The constructor. The constructor is called before the initialize()
     * method.
     * 
     * Anything in regards to CSS styling with FXML MUST be done within the initialize method.
     */

    public graphicalController() {

    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */

    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {

        centreButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Play_Button.png')");
        centreButton.setText("");

        backButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Back_Button.png')");
        backButton.setText("");

        forwardButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/Forward_Button.png')");
        forwardButton.setText("");

        muteToggle.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/Resources/ToggleSound_Button.png')");
        muteToggle.setText("");

        nameText.setText("");
        albumText.setText("");
        artistText.setText("");

        volumeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                    double sliderValue = newValue.intValue();
                    handleVolumeSlider(sliderValue);
                }
            });

        timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

                    //outputTextArea.appendText("Slider Value Changed (newValue: " + newValue.intValue() + ")\n");
                }
            });

        timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
                public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
                    if (timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
                        // multiply duration by percentage calculated by slider position
                        if(duration!=null) {
                            player.seek(duration.multiply(timeSlider.getValue() / 100.0));
                        }
                        updateValues();
                    }
                }
            });

    }


    public void setSongText() {
        String file = q.peek().fileName;
        String songName = q.peek().songName;
        String albumName = q.peek().albumName;
        String artistName = q.peek().artistName;
        if (songName == "") {
            songName = "Song name not specified in metadata.";
        }
        else if (albumName == "")
        {
            albumName = " Album name not specified in metadata.";
        }
        else if (artistName == "")
        {
            artistName = "Artist name not specified in metadata.";
        }
        nameText.setText(songName);
        albumText.setText(albumName);
        artistText.setText(artistName);
    }
}
```

You will find my problem in the initialize method.

Comment: I strongly suspect you don't *really* need 319 lines of code to demonstrate your problem. Please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: Fair point. I done it out of not laziness, I just thought understanding the whole program would be a better option. However, you are right, there are some methods I can delete which are not part of this problem. Standby, I'll do it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the correct `Observable` type? It should be of type `javafx.beans.Observable`.

Comment: Oh man. I am literally hitting my head on a table right now. Usually eclipse would suggest if I needed a import a new thing. Apparently not, thanks for identifying that. Would not survive if it wasn't for this community!